# Transformation of a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my lecture notes there is the following ODE

$$y''+ky=0,\quad y_{1}=\cos\sqrt{kx},\; y_{2}=\sin\sqrt{kx}$$

In order to be solved the following transformation is used

$$y(x)=z[r(x)]$$

The notes conclude that the initial ODE is transformed into the

$$z''_{rr}+z=0$$

How can the the one be equivalent to the other? How we go from the first to the second?? Shouldn't there be a $k$ in the last one?

Comment: It must be $y_1=\cos\left( \sqrt{k}\cdot x\right)$, $y_2=\sin\left( \sqrt{k}\cdot x\right)$

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos No the notes are pretty clear that both $k$ and $x$ are under the root.

Comment: The notation is a bit strange. Writing $y(x) = z(a x)$, we get $a^2 z'' + k z = 0$, so if $k > 0$, we can fix $a = \sqrt{k}$, giving $k z'' + k z = 0$, or $z'' + z = 0$.

Comment: @Adam Maybe a typo in the lecture notes, with either $y_1=\cos(\sqrt{kx})$ or $y_2=\sin (\sqrt{kx})$,the equality $$y''+ky=0$$ doesn't hold

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos It is possible. I will check it, thanks!